# Excel VBA - Moving a column down

Tags: vba, excel

I have a portion of my script that needs to move a column down, so that the start of the new column is at the end of the column next to it. For example, if column "A" is 229 Lines, Column "B" would start at line 230.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 O = Range("H" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 Q = Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

 Range("I" & Q).Cut Range("I" & O + 1)
```

Where O and Q are both longs. I have tested that O and Q are getting the correct number of lines. But when I try to move it down, it does not move anything. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are cutting the last cell only, not the whole populated column. You can try this:

```
Range("I1:I" & Q).Cut Range("I" & O + 1)
```